# Extract hourly component from time column

Tags: python, pandas, time

For the following dataframe "Schedule", how does one create the column "Hour_Number" from the column Time_Stamp which lists the time in HH:MM or H:MM format?

Output:

```
     Time_Stamp    Hour_Number
  0  11:16         11
  1  14:19         14
  2  13:02         13
  3  2:12          2
  4  7:15          7
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `str.split` to split on colon, and then extract the first item with the `.str` accessor:

```
df['Hour_Number'] = df.Time_Stamp.str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)
```

An alternative would be a conversion to `datetime` using `to_datetime` and then extracting the `hour` component:

```
df['Hour_Number'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time_Stamp).dt.hour
```

```
df
  Time_Stamp  Hour_Number
0      11:16           11
1      14:19           14
2      13:02           13
3       2:12            2
4       7:15            7
```